# Probability that digits are at their proper places of $n$ possibilities

Tags: probability

I can't solve this question although I have tried many times.

Question : Let $n>1$ , suppose that $n$ numbers are written down in random order.

${1,2,...,n}$

Number is said to be in the "right place" if for example 2 is located in the 2nd place.

1)What is the probability that 2 numbers will be in the right place ?

2)what is the probability that **atleast** 2 numbers will be in the right place?

My try (for the question number 2) :

all the probabilities are $n!$, $A$ is wanted probability, I chose $2Cn$ and the probabilities for the others is $(n-2)!$.

I got $\frac {A}{n!} = \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Are you familiar with Derangement? Both questions are pretty direct application of that.

Answer (score 1):

Number of arrangements where exactly two numbers are in the right places is a derangement of $(n-2)$ and the way to choose $2$ numbers that are in right places.

So, Number of favorable arrangements for $(1) = {n \choose 2} \times \, !(n-2)$

For second question, find the number of arrangements that have at most one number in the right place $( = \, !n + n \times \, !(n-1))$ and subtract from $n!$.

Now use these to find desired probability.